# display list of values of a specific variable or control's property in level on from or application

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

how can I display the list of value or values of a specific variable or control's property on the level of form(class) or application(no matter in design time or at compile time) so that in that list we want to see the value and place of assignment that variable?

I tried with find references option but it works only in class level and does not display the value and execution order of the variable.

Comment: Please, show us your code.

Comment: And yet you've read the Tour. Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: how can I trace inside of imported assembly that has also its source code in another project?